# splitting value with comma but ignoring if that value contains more that 1 data

Tags: regex, split

I have a string field like this:
[num=0388, name=karl,steve,moo, age=1]

I want to split these value into like this

num=0338;name=karl,steve,moo;age=1

however current actual output im getting since im splitting it when theres a comma looks like this:
num=0338;name=kar;steve;moo;age=1

Is there any idea how i am able to get the expected value? can i do it using regex code?

Comment: pls explain how are you splitting it.

Comment: I have this code that split the value inside the CDT.

So for example I have a CTD:

'type!{urn:com:appian:types}T_Sample'(
  name: "Person",

  place: "City1,City2,City3"

  
)

When splitting the value, the output should be like this in an array form:

Expected: ["Person"; "City1,City2, City3"]

But the actual result I got is:  ["Person"; "City1"; "City2; "City3"]

the place where split in different index where it shouldn't be.

This is my current code:

Comment: local!splittedCDT:split(
    stripwith(
      tostring(
        ri!cdtVal
      ),
      "[] "
    ),
    ","
)
    
 local!updatedVal: a!forEach(
    items: local!splittedCDT,
    expression: replace(fv!item, 0, find("=", fv!item, 0), "")
  ),

Comment: Im using appian platform

Comment: Anyways, i just want if the value of the cdt contains more than 1 data. it wont be splitted into different index. like the example: CDT[name: "Person", place: "City1,City2,City3"], expected output must be: ["person"; "City1, City2,City3"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a split on either `[`, `]`, or `,`  (comma space), then filtered for non-empty itesm, then combined with `;` delimiter:

```js
const input = '[num=0388, name=karl,steve,moo, age=1]';
const regex = /[\[\]]|, /;
const result = input.split(regex).filter(Boolean).join(';');
console.log(result);
```

Ouput:

```
num=0388;name=karl,steve,moo;age=1
```